# Regex to validate several ranges of values (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the option to use a regex to validate some values and I would like to know the best way to do it.

I have several ranges (not in the same regex/validation) such as 1-9 (this is easy :P), and:

1-99
1-999
1-9999

Also, I need to check for leading zeros, so, 0432 is a possible match.

I know that Regex might not be the best approach for this, but it's what I have, and it's part of a framework I have to use.

Comment: Please give more details on what you want, preferably with examples on valid and invalid values.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **fundamental flaw** with all other answers!!

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("9999", @"\d{1,3}");
```

Returns true although the number is not a 1-3 digit number. That is because part of the word matches the expression.

You needs to use:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("9999", @"^\d{1,n}$");
```

Where n is the maximum number of digits.

**UPDATE**

In order to make sure it is not zero, change it to below:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("9999", @"(^\d{2,n}$)|[1-9]");
```

**UPDATE 2**
It still would not work if we have 00 or 000 or 0000. My brain hurts, I will have a look again later. We can do it as two expressions ("(^\d{2,n}$)|[1-9]" and NOT (0)|(00)|(000)|(0000)) but that probably is not accepted as a SINGLE regex answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (*n* is the amount of numbers):

```
[0-9]{n}
```

Comment: Hello Bobby. I tried this way. but sometimes I don't want the first 0.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% clear on what you want but perhaps something like this?

```
\d{1,2}
```

This is the equivalent to `\d\d?` and will match any one- or two-digit number, that is any number from 0 to 99, including leading zeros.

If you really want to exclude `0`, then things get *a lot* more complicated.

Basically, you need to check for 1–9 and 01–09 explicitly. The third group of allowed numbers will have two digits that do *not* start with a zero:

```
0?[123456789]|[123456789]\d
```

Now the part before the `|` will check whether it’s a number below 10, with optional leading zero. The second alternative will check whether it’s a two-digit number *not* starting with a zero.

The rest of the ranges can be checked by extending this.